# Printing response in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test I can't get to work, so I want to debug my spec by printing the reponse.

I've tried using `print response.body` in my spec, but there's no output in either test.log or the console.

I'm probably missing something. What should I try?

Thanks!

Comment: `puts response.body`? And it should be before error raising

Comment: You should provide more information, such as the minimal amount of the spec file to create the issue.

Comment: fl00r, I got it working using puts. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can print the response using:

```
raise response.body
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$stderr.puts response.body
```

To print your Response. But I will suggest to just use above code for testing and remove any puts from RSpec Unit test it is considered bad practice to write RSpec code that output something.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use

```
puts response.body
```