# How do we print response body in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write an rspec file for my meetings_controller.rb so as to check if the values returned from my database are correct.

When I go to localhost:3000/meeting.json, this is the result of my data from the database

[image]

my rspec file is trying to check if the correct values are returned.

I created a folder called controller under specs (after I have installed rspec)and have the file meeting_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

# Change this ArticlesController to your project
RSpec.describe MeetingsController, type: :controller do

    describe "GET #index" do
        # check index
        it "returns a success response" do
            get :index
            puts response.body
            expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
            
        end

    end
end
```

I tried to print the response body but nothing is returning. Is there a way to do this?

```
(base) adam-a01:reservation adrianlee$ rspec

.

Finished in 0.0892 seconds (files took 12.15 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Btw this is my meeting_controller.rb

```
class MeetingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_meeting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /meetings
  # GET /meetings.json
  def index
    @meetings = Meeting.all
    @meeting = Meeting.new

  end
end
```

Update: I also tried this method as suggested below but it didnt work still

```
# Change this ArticlesController to your project
RSpec.describe MeetingsController, type: :controller do

    describe "GET #index" do
        # check index
        it "returns a success response" do
            get :index
            raise response.body 
            expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
            
        end

    end
end
```

This is the error raised
Failures:

```
  1) MeetingsController GET #index returns a success response
     Failure/Error: raise response.body
     RuntimeError:
     # ./spec/controllers/meeting_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing response in rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225767/printing-response-in-rspec)

Comment: I  tried this as well and it didnt work actually. edited my  answer

Comment: Are you trying to get this value for a debugging purpose?

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint in there and inspect the response. Is response.body nil? What is the status code?

Comment: I'm using `raise response.body.inspect`. But this will give the test case an error since it raises a runtime error but I can see the value in the console.

Comment: Im trying to print my index values to see if the data retrieved is correct. I have updated my question to be more precise

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get this value for a debugging purpose you should use `byebug` or `pry` gems.

If you choose byebug, add it to your gemfile `gem 'byebug'` on test environment.
run `bundle install` and after that you are able to use it on your tests

So replace the `puts` with `byebug`

```
describe "GET #index" do
   # check index
   it "returns a success response" do
     get :index
     byebug
     expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok) 
       
   end

end
```

At the console now you are exactly there. Just type `response.body` and `enter` to print it's value.
When you are done, just type `c` and then `enter` to release the console e continue your tests.

Also [check here](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) for more information about debugging with byebug

Answer (score 0):

In my case I do it like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe SuppliersController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET /suppliers' do
    let!(:access_token) { create :access_token }
    let!(:admin_user_token) do
      create :user_token, resource_owner: create(:admin_user)
    end

    context 'when the requester is an admin' do
      it 'returns HTTP status 200 (OK)' do
        allow(controller).to receive(:doorkeeper_token) { access_token }
        @request.env['HTTP_X_USERTOKEN'] = admin_user_token.token

        get :index

        raise response.body.inspect ## Here is what prints the value in the console.

        body = JSON.parse response.body

        expect(response).to have_http_status :ok
        expect(body['status']).to eq 'OK'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To run the test:

```
rspec spec/controllers/suppliers/suppliers_controller_index_spec.rb
```

And it gives me the output:

```
F

Failures:

  1) SuppliersController GET /suppliers when the requester is an admin returns HTTP status 200 (OK)
     Failure/Error: raise response.body.inspect
     
     RuntimeError:
       "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Your request has been processed successfully.\",\"data\":[],\"page\":{\"current_page\":1,\"prev_page\":null,\"next_page\":null,\"per_page\":25,\"total_pages\":0}}"
     # ./spec/controllers/suppliers/suppliers_controller_index_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.47594 seconds (files took 2.82 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/suppliers/suppliers_controller_index_spec.rb:11 # SuppliersController GET /suppliers when the requester is an admin returns HTTP status 200 (OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say raise a runtime error to check variable value is not a good practice,maybe you should try `gem 'pry'` or `gem 'byebug'` suggested by @DR7.
Another thing you need make sure is did you run `rails  s` and `rspec` in different environment?This maybe lead to they connect to separate db.